# Unsupervised Clustering based entirely on entity similarity

Tags: c#, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, cluster-analysis, encog

I'm trying to cluster a number of entities. The only metric I have for clustering is the similarity between one entity and another. (a 0-1 float)

Can anyone think of any clustering algorithms that would achieve this?
I appreciate it would be returning fuzzy groups. That's still a better solution than estimating groups programatically as I am at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All clustering algorithms that act on networks (also known as graphs - nodes connected by edges) that take into account neighbourhood topology. Many of these exist. I recommend RNSC and MCL (disclaimer: I wrote the latter). To elaborate, cluster structure in simple (unweighted) networks can exist in the form of node sets where many of the possible connections are realised.

Comment: MCL looks to suit the bill perfectly. Thanks for that. Do you know of any links demonstrating its use programatically?

Comment: Do you mean to embed a bit of code that implements mcl, as opposed to calling an mcl implementation as a separate program externally? Regarding the first, mcl is relatively easy to implement (there is a very small perl implementation on the micans.org/mcl website), and regarding the latter a robust implementation does exist already; however perhaps you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, Ideally I want to be able to optimise it for use within SQL server. So far have picked through
http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~xyan/classes/CS595D-2009winter/MCL_Presentation2.pdf
Which was brilliant in explaining MCL.

Comment: For others interested, the perl example is available at:
http://micans.org/mcl/index.html.bu
It wasn't very clear as to how to get there from the home page.

Comment: Wow, good find. The direct link is http://micans.org/mcl/scripts/minimcl (reachable from 'news & views' - the website could very much be improved in terms of structure). I was not sure what you needed, and the perl example is perhaps not a paragon of clarity. In case this is useful to anyone, I'll mention that the micans.org mcl implementation does allow UNIX-type streaming. It is possible to pipe to and read from 'mcl - --abc  -o - -V all'. The --abc option implies that a three column 'label label weight' form needs to be supplied.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DBSCAN (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) or [OPTICS (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPTICS_algorithm). While they talk about distances, they do not require metric properties or anything - they can be used with similarity functions just as well!

Comment: I'll slightly misuse the comment system here and mention that the next mcl release will have an implementation of OPTICS. This is an interesting approach, although in my view not a complete solution either but *no* single algorithm will ever be. It is (more) robust compared to classic linkage algorithms (especially single linkage) due to the density based approach, but still very much part of this family. I think the density plot generated by optics can be quite informative and useful in general though, without necessarily following up with the clustering approach.

Comment: @micans will it have a full OPTICS implementation with Xi cluster extraction, or the incomplete DBSCAN style stuff that everybody copies from Weka?

Comment: How does it compare benchmarking-wise with the ELKI implementation? That is a pretty fast implementation AFAICT.

Comment: I've implemented it from reading the OPTICS paper, which was not entirely straightforward to parse, hence more verification and testing are needed. The approach is to divide it in stages: Stage 1 outputs the ordered reachability values and a corresponding Postscript reachability plot (now done), stage 2 is a simple script that uses the reachability values to create a clustering. For testing I will also have code that colors 2D plots according to the optics classification. Spatial indexes are not yet supported (but mcxarray is fast parallellised brute-force). Would you be interested in testing?

Comment: I haven't compared with ELKI yet. The mcl-edge implementation is bound to be pretty fast once the input graph is created. This is how I would implement it even with a spatial index: Build a graph from the index rather than interfacing with the index for every pairwise operation in OPTICS. This could well be how ELKI does it too - I don't know.